# Entries of Unitarily Similary Matrics

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If two matrices $A$ and $B$ are unitarily equivalent ($QAQ^{*} = B$ for some unitary matrix $Q$), what can we say about the entries of $B$? Is there a concise way to express its entries in terms of the column vectors of $A$ and $Q$? It seems like some entries, especially the diagonal entries, of $B$ should have a simple formulation.

Comment: *"It seems like some entries, especially the diagonal entries, of B should have a simple formulation:"* not sure what you mean by this.  The matrices
$$
\pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}, \quad \pmatrix{2&0\\0&0}
$$
are unitarily equivalent, but I don't see what we can say about their diagonal entries.

Comment: $Q = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{1&1\\1&-1}$
Right? It looks like the $i$-th diagonal entry follows the pattern $q_i^{*}Aq_i$ where $q_i$ is the $i$-th column of $Q$, but I'm not sure if that is a general property and why.

Comment: Oh, that's what you mean.  Sure, that's correct; answer coming up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $Q$ has columns $q_1,\dots,q_n$.  We can then write the matrix product as
$$
Q^*AQ = \pmatrix{q_1^*\\q_2^* \\ \vdots \\ q_n^*}\ A \ \pmatrix{q_1 & q_2 & \cdots & q_n}
$$
With [block-matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix), we can write this product as
$$
Q^*AQ = \pmatrix{q_1^*Aq_1 & \cdots & q_1^*A q_n\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
q_n^*Aq_1 & \cdots & q_n^*Aq_n}
$$

Comment: This is true for arbitrary matrices $B^{*}AC = \pmatrix{b_1^*Ac_1 & \cdots & b_1^*A c_n\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
b_n^*Ac_1 & \cdots & b_n^*Ac_n}$. So we don't gain anything by knowing that $q_i^{*}q_j = \delta_{ij}$?

Comment: Nothing towards an expression for the entries, no.